# Java Command Line Application

Tags: java, command-line

I'm a newbie to Java and software engineering and had the following question. What exactly does it mean to build a Java Command Line application? In particular, should the application be such that it can run by an individual using Command Line (with the program in some file on the user's desktop and the application be a java file) and all the source code should be written in Java?  I understand what Command Line is and my JDK is Eclipse. Thanks for the clarification (couldn't find sufficient explanation online).

Comment: A CLI is any program run from the command line, taking in arguments that affect the operation.  I don't know, think `cp` (or `copy`).  It has no GUI and it's operations are all carried out at the command line

Comment: Ok got it. If you write a program in Java in Eclipse, does that automatically use Swing/GUI?

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE, not a JDK. the JDK is de Java Development Kit. No. No program, no matter in what IDE (or without IDE) you write it, has 'automatically' a GUI. If you don't add one, there isn't one.

You can use Scanner to read input from the command prompt, and print statements to put your output there.

Comment: Ok thanks - my question as a follow up would be: If you write source code in Eclipse or whatever IDE, do you have to do anything special to incorporate CLI or GUI? What is the default?

Comment: as answered on your (identical) question on wwweagle's answer: if you want to have a GUI, you'll have to create it. There is no default. It depends on your needs.

Comment: @don there's no default. If you use classes and method that show a GUI you get a GUI application, if you use classes and methods that interact with a command line you get a CLI application

Comment: Ok thanks - what do I need to do to write a Java Command Line program? Just a guideline or generally idea would be helpful - I can browse around to figure out the implementation details

Comment: @don that's too vague a question. What does your application need to do?

Comment: @don I already answered that. Scanner and print statements

Comment: Ok thanks Federico - what would the right classes/methods as a guideline be for writing a CLI? I will look around to find the details

Comment: Ok thanks. My application will ultimately need to browse a website and crawl and scrape data

Comment: @don no problem, but really, follow a Java tutorial (like the one from Oracle) or read a book. All your questions can be answered by following the first page with code on any of those.

Comment: @don don't try to rush things. If you are only now trying to figure out how to create a command line application, creating a webcrawler is most likely out of your league. Probably you'll need to be able to use third party libraries, but you'll need to know networking and such. You don't learn this in just a day or two.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I do have some experience with other languages and such. Honestly, I think I've reached a point where I need to just build stuff (this is tough but I think I can grind through and have built similar projects in the past)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generally means there is no graphic user interface (aka, GUI) in you program, so people could use it in text terminals without a graphic display (embeded, remote server, etc). I believe the default setting in Eclipse new projects are command line applications, so no additional efforts needed.

Comment: Ok thanks - my question as a follow up would be: If you write source code in Eclipse or whatever IDE, do you have to do anything special to incorporate CLI or GUI? What is the default?

Comment: @don you have to create a GUI.

Comment: Ok thanks - what do I need to do to write a Java Command Line program? Just a guideline or generally idea would be helpful - I can browse around to figure out the implementation details

Comment: @don just follow any Eclipse "new project" tutorial. They almost always start with a command line app.

Comment: One thing to remember is that very few CLI Programs have any sort of interactive interface. Most get all their data through the initial command line and arguments. Ex: mv file1 ../

Answer (score 3):

A CLI program is a program that uses the command line as its interface.

For example,

```
cp file1 ../
```

If such a program requires some continuing interaction with the user, then Java programs typically use System.out to print output, and a Scanner object for input.

```
Scanner ins = new Scanner(Sytem.in);
```

The user types on the keyboard. The Scanner doesn't get the input until the user presses the return key.

For example, to request a name from a user

```
Scanner ins = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = "";

while (name.equals("")) {
  System.out.print("Your name? ");
  name = ins.next();
}
```

There should be more error checking and so forth, but the basupics are there. I hope this helps.